# How does in-line editing editing work in CiviCRM?

Tags: extension, developer

Is there a reference anywhere for the in-line editing, e.g., 'Click Here to Edit' in CiviCRM? I need something similar for my extension and want to reuse as much as I can.

Comment: Please elaborate your question a little more and what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an API that allows to modify the entity you want (if it's a custom one, it's easy to add), adding a few classes should be enough to enable the edit in place. You need to define the entity that contain the field (class crm-entity, id "type-{id}" on a containing dom node and then "crm-editable crmf-{fieldname}". for example:

```
<table>
  <tr class="crm-entity" id="contact-123">

    <!-- textfield (default type) -->
    <td class="crm-editable crmf-first_name">Fred</td>

    <!-- select list with empty option -->
    <!-- (note: options will be fetched automatically by the api) -->
    <td class="crm-editable crmf-prefix_id"
        data-type="select"
        data-empty-option="{ts}- none -{/ts}">Mr.</td>

    <!-- yes/no select -->
    <td class="crm-editable crmf-is_deceased" data-type="boolean">
      No
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

More details in the doc

https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/ui/#in-place-field-editing

Comment: Thanks. That link is just what I needed. Not sure why I couldn't find it before.